# Can you Sign The agents in a database programmatically?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotusscript, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

Is there a way to programmatically sign the agents in a database?  I'd like to use a run on server agent to sign the agents of a database that I pass it.  I'd like to do this using LotusScript or an XPage.

MJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods in both answers are correct. But they will work on notes client...

Signing any document needs a private key which exists in your ID file. Therefore, normally, you cannot sign an agent with a code that doesn't run on Notes client.

However, there are products (e.g. [Ytria SignEZ](http://www.ytria.com/WebSite.nsf/WebPageRequest/Solutions_signEZen)) using C-API to sign design elements but they cache necessary ID file in a secure storage (with recent versions ID Vault can be used for this but I don't know how much portion of API is open for us).

UPDATE: As Fredrik said, signing with server id is always possible via Admin request.

Answer (score 6):

in Lotusscript run this code with the Signer ID preferable in an agent

```
Dim session As New Notessession 
Dim db As Notesdatabase 
Set db = session.Currentdatabase 
Call db.sign(DBSIGN_DOC_ALL)
```

in SSJS

```
var DB:NotesDatabase=sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(database.getServer(),database.getFilePath());
DB.sign(NotesDatabase.DBSIGN_DOC_ALL)
```

=================

## Update

lotusscript

```
dim AdminPNotesId
dim AdminP as NotesAdministrationProcess
Set  AdminP =  notesSession.CreateAdministrationProcess(Server)
AdminpNoteId=AdminP.SignDatabaseWithServerID(Server,Database)
```

SSJS

```
var AdminP=sessionAsSigner.CreateAdministrationProcess(Server)
var AdminPNoteID=AdminP.SignDatabaseWithServerID(Server,Database)
```

Comment: But this runs only in the client, not on the server, or am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks Sven for correcting me, Was a bit fast there :-)
The correct way is to use The AdminP process and the function signDatabaseWithServerID(Server,Database)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this several years ago using a LS agent. I remember it went like this:

1. get a NotesNoteCollection containing all agents
2. loop through the collection accessing all its noteIds
3. access each design doc using those noteIds and check if it points to the wanted agent
4. sign the agent's design doc using

   NotesDocument.Sign

I never tried to do that using SSJS though. But it works at least using an agent signed with an appropriate ID (see updates below)

**edit 1:** 
@Sven: of course, I forgot to mention that you need to save your design doc after signing...

**edit 2:**
@Serdar: you're right: to sign an agent I need the signer's Notes ID, so Fred's updated solution is the one

Comment: 5. you have to save the document with *NotesDocument.save* ;-)